# Execute as player wearing tagged armor

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How would you test for a player *wearing* (Not just having in their inventory) a piece of armor with a tag? Testing just like
 `/execute as @a[nbt={Inventory:[{Tag:{Tags:["TagName"]}}]}] run say hi` will only test for the inventory, and I'm not sure how to specify the slot.

Answer (score 2):

To detect the player wearing the armor, we'll want to test for the tag in the actual slot itself. Adding the `Slot` criteria to the nbt selector, we can test for the tag specifically in that one slot.

`/execute as @a[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:102b,tag:{Tags:["TagName"]}}]}] run say hi`

The inventory IDs are:

**103** : Head / Helmet

**102** : Chest / Chestplate

**101** : Legs / Leggings

**100** : Feet / Boots

You can find the rest of the slot IDs here: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Inventory

Answer (score 2):

Scoreboard tags that you may give to an item entity with `/tag` will disappear once the item is picked up, you can use custom NBT tags though.

You can give yourself a tagged iron helmet with this command:

```
/give @s minecraft:iron_helmet{customTag:1}
```

You can use this command to execute as every player who has an item with `customTag:1` in the head slot:

```
/execute as @a[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:103b,tag:{customTag:1}}]}] run say hi
```

You have to use a different number for the slot depending on what slot the item is supposed to be in. You can figure out the ID by first clearing your inventory and placing an item in that slot. Then run `/data get entity @s Inventory` and you will get all the information about that slot and the item.

The armor slot IDs are `100b` for boots, `101b` for leggings, `102b` for elytras or chestplates, and `103b` for helmets or mobheads.